# $mail->AddAddress() causing trouble with executing code

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am a beginner to phpmailer. I followed the instructions and copied their code for my small project. Now there seems to be a problem with 
$mail->AddAddress(). After the line the execution stops and non further line is executed. Here is my code:-

```
//some db details hidden
$x = mysqli_fetch_array($sqll);
$vcode = $x['vcode'];
$name = $x['name'];
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "sidhurockz55@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "Password";
$mail->From  =  "sidhurockz55@gmail.com";
$mail->Subject = "Verify Email";
$mail->AddAddress($email,$name);
```

This is the Source Code displayed when this code is used:-

[image]

When I comment the $mail->AddAddress($email,$name);. The full source code is displayed:-
          [image]

Comment: what is in your error log?

Comment: i think it should be `$mail->addAddress($email,$name);` with a small `a`

Comment: `AddAddress()` is correct (with capital A). I can't see `$email` defined anywhere. BTW, as @bansi said you should look on your error log to find out.

Comment: Probably `$email` that's undefined. Try `var_dump($email);` to see if anything is outputted (Or verify it's set first)

Comment: $email is set @ the top of the page as $email=$_GET['email'];

Comment: And there is nothing in the error logs. I replaced the $email=$_GET['email']; to $email='email@server.com', but still nothin'

Comment: Does `AddAddress` return something (by docs it should return true or false)? Also you can add `$mail->exceptions = true` to get more debug information.